# OpenTK orthographic projection with left top origin

Tags: c#, opengl, projection, opentk

How do I setup openTK so I get a orthographic projection where:

- The origin is in the top left corner of the screen
- I can use "normal" pixel coordinates, for instance: if my window is 500 X 400 then:

  - 0,0 is the top left corner
  - 500,0 is the top right corner
  - 500,400 is the bottom right corner
  - 0,400 is the bottom left corner

I currenly have this:

```cs
_projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
    ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Width,
    ClientRectangle.Y, ClientRectangle.Height, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

I'm not fully able to understand what's happening but is seems the origin is now in the bottom left, also I don't know if the coordinates match with the pixels on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to [`Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.matrix4.createorthographicoffcenter?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) are the `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`, `near`, and `far` of the cuboid view volume.

If the origin of the view (`ClientRectangle.Y`) has to be at the top, then you've to swap the `top` and `bottom` parameter:

```
_projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
    ClientRectangle.X, 
    ClientRectangle.X + ClientRectangle.Width,
    ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height, 
    ClientRectangle.Y,
    -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: That worked! except for the fact that my text is now upside-down: https://imgur.com/a/gvLdwFo the text is rendered using QuickFont. Any Ideas?

Comment: Of course the text is upside down. That was what you wanted to do. Before the change, the origin was at the bottom and the y direction was upwards. Now the origin is at the top and the y direction is downwards. You've to change the text rendering to compensate that.